# What is the broadcast ip address for all networks?

Tags: server, network-programming, ip, broadcasting

I have learned that

1. Limited broadcasting is broadcasting in same network.
2. Directed broadcasting is broadcasting in other network.

But what about the broadcast in all network?

Comment: It is 255.255.255.255, but you can't use it to reach all networks, as it was deprecated 25 or more years ago.

Comment: Broadcasts do not cross routers. You can only broadcast on your own network, but broadcast is a legacy remnant that should not be used. The modern way is multicast. IPv6 does not have broadcast, and many companies will not consider applications that use broadcast.